# system slowed by many "lib" tasks and boot shows several errors

Tags: startup

Heres the system log after startup:

```
12:37:19 systemd: Failed to start Firmware update daemon.
12:35:17 pulseaudio: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
12:34:19 avahi-daemon: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
12:34:11 (sd-executor): /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/friendly-recovery failed with exit status 1.
```

Comment: These messages may or may not indicate that something is wrong with your system. Do you have an actual problem? Also please specify your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Ubuntu version is 20.04 (5.15.0-67).  Problem is the speed of molasses.  I added the boot flag "intel_iommu=off" and it helped a little.  It may be that Ubuntu has grown too big for my older machine (Dell GX620), but it's been fine till about a month ago.  I suspect either an automatic update or my installation of GCC, although I haven't run GCC yet.